# Change Parent layout from setOnItemClickListener()

Tags: android, events, android-activity, listener

I have an `Activity a`  with a `ListView lv` inside.

I have set the `lv.setOnItemClickListener()`.

When the user clicks on a **list item** i want another list view (`ListView lv_2`) in the `Activity a` to be refreshed.

Problem is that i cannot access the **Parent** `Activity a` inside `lv.setOnItemClickListener()` am i right?

I studied some of custom event listeners but i don't understand how to use them in this particular case.

So how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
lv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        lv2Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv2.setAdapter(lv2Adapter);
        lv2.notify();

    }
});
```